# Install Ubuntu side by side with Windows 7 on existing RAID 5 array

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, raid

I've got Windows alreay installed on Raid5 array with 3x1TB HDD. I want to install Ubuntu on one partition in this array, but Ubuntu Setup doesn't recognize the array. All that I have found is instruction on how to make "new" RAID 5 array and setup the Ubuntu there, but the problem is that I do not have spare 2TB to copy all the stuff there and make partitions from Ubuntu setup.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What is the current RAID controller?

Answer (score 1):

Most "RAID BIOS" built into motherboards are actually a software RAID, not a true hardware RAID, which is why Ubuntu doesn't see it.

What I would try to do is backup your RAID setup, all your data, etc. Then try re-creating the RAID setup with Ubuntu using mdadmin.

By this I don't mean start over, but setup mdadmin to replicate your existing raid setup, and install Ubuntu on that other partition you want to create. It might be possible that setting up the Linux software RAID to mimic the "BIOS RAID", you can actually use both windows and Linux on this RAID setup.

If you want a solution that is really going to work, you need to buy a real hardware RAID card, they're normally $200+.